# How to execute SQL Script which may or may not return data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, ado

This is an extension [of an old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927761/what-are-all-the-possible-first-words-of-sql-statements) where the answer wasn't quite what I was asking. What I'm doing is executing SQL Script on an MS SQL Server database. This script *may or may not* return any recordsets. The problem is that the way that ADO components work, at least to my knowledge, I can only explicitly request one or the other.

- If I know a query will return data, I use `TADOQuery.Open`
- If I know a query will not return data, I use `TADOConnection.Execute`
- If I don't know whether query will return data or not... ???

How can I execute any query and read the response to determine whether it has any recordsets or not so I can read that recordset?

What I've tried:

1. Calling `TADOQuery.Open`, but raises exception if there's no recordset
2. Calling `TADOQuery.ExecSql`, but never returns any data
3. Calling `TADOConnection.Execute`, but never returns any data
4. Using Option `3` and reverting to Option `1` on exceptions, but this is double the work (script files over 38,000 lines) and kinda nasty.
5. Using `TADOCommand.Execute`, but keeps raising "Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided" on creating some stored procedures (which otherwise don't happen when using `TADOConnection.Execute`).
6. Calling `TADOConnection.Execute` overload which returns `_Recordset`, but then the `TADOConnection.Errors` returns empty (and I depend on this).

Just as some background, the purpose is to implement something like the SQL Query tool in the SQL Server Management Studio. It allows you to execute any SQL script, and if it returns any recordsets, it displays them, otherwise it just displays output messages. The tool I'm working on automatically breaks SQL Script at `GO` statements, and executes each individual block separately. Some of those blocks might return data, and others might not. It's already obvious that I cannot make this determination prior to execution, so I'm looking for a way to go ahead with the execution and observe the result. `TADOConnection.Execute` provides some useful information, including the `Errors` (or output messages).

As of now, the only option I have is to supply an option in the user interface to allow the user to choose which type of execution to use - but this is what I'm trying to eliminate.

---

**EDIT**

The `TADOCommand.Execute` method is the closest to what I want. However, it fails on some bits of script which otherwise work perfectly fine using `TADOConnection.Execute`. See #5 above in "What I've tried". I almost wrote that as my answer, until I found this error happens on almost everything.

---

**EDIT**

After posting my answer below, I then came to learn that the `Errors` property no longer returns anything when I use this other overload of `Execute`. See #6 above in "What I've tried".

Calling...

```
ADOConnection1.Execute('select * from something', cmdText, []);
```

...does not return anything in `ADOConnection1.Errors`, whereas...

```
var
  R: Integer;
begin
  ADOConnection1.Execute('select * from something', R);
```

...does return messages in `ADOConnection1.Errors`, which is what I need, but yet, doesn't return any recordsets.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I should just use the raw OLE automation instead.

Comment: Where's Schrodinger when you need him?

Comment: Simply add another statement with a simple select open and check the count of resultsets. More than one? You have a result from the original statement. Thats it

Comment: @SirRufo That was trial #4 above, I didn't make that one clear enough. But the problem is deeper - read my latest edits / answer.

Comment: Related/Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/15730967/937125

Comment: @kobik Related, but not duplicate. That question is much more broad in the sense of a one-for-all function.

Comment: Isn't that answers your question too? I think it does.

Comment: @kobik No, the answer to that question still has the problem I describe. When using the version of `TADOConnection.Execute` which returns a recordset, it does not report any messages / errors as it should, as it does if I don't use that version of Execute. That Q/A is what already got me to where I am now.

Comment: Just for the record, here's the file/project I'm working on where I'm facing this problem, currently solved by providing two different types of execution: https://github.com/djjd47130/sql-executer/blob/master/SQLExec.pas within the very last procedure `function TSQLExec.Execute: TSQLExecResult;` in the subroutine `DoExec`

Comment: can you give an example of a SQL that fails and what error you expect to see.

Comment: @kobik At this time, it's not that any SQL is failing. It's that the "Errors" property comes back empty when I use the overload version of `Execute` that I need. Errors, being actually output messages, such as if a `PRINT` command is in the SQL script. `PRINT 'Some Test'` appears in the list of errors (which is exactly what I need), but only if I use the overload version which doesn't return the data.

Comment: I didn't know that `PRINT`command  would appear in the Errors property... I'll check into that when I can.

Comment: @kobik Or otherwise any type of output messages, the ones you'd see in SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Not the right solution**

I discovered my solution finally after digging even deeper. The answer is to use the `TADOConnection.Execute()` overload which supports returning the recordset:

```
function TADOConnection.Execute(const CommandText: WideString;
  const CommandType: TCommandType = cmdText;
  const ExecuteOptions: TExecuteOptions = []): _Recordset;
```

Then, just assign the resulting `_Recordset` to the `Recordset` property of supported dataset components.

```
var
  RS: _Recordset;
begin
  RS := ADOConnection1.Execute('select * from something', cmdText, []);
  if Assigned(RS) then begin
    ADODataset1.Recordset:= RS;
    ...
  end;
end;
```

The downside is that you cannot use the other overload which supports returning the `RowsAffected`. Also, nothing is returned in the `Errors` property of the `TADOConnection` when using this overload version of `Execute`, whereas the other one does. But that other doesn't return a recordset.

Comment: Sadly, when using this overload, it does not return any messages in the `Errors`. That only seems to work when using the overload version I was using before.